# How do I enable (onSelect) event handler to run first and prevent (onBlur) event from running as well using PrimeNG autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have a situation here and I was looking for some help. Currently developing a search autocomplete feature where options are displayed from a predefined list in the component. Now, this is how my p-autocomplete tag looks like:

```
 <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="skills" [suggestions]="filteredSkillSuggestions"
           id="skills" name="skills" #skillList="ngModel" 
           (completeMethod)="search($event)"
           [dropdown]="false" 
           [unique]="true"
           [multiple]="true"
           (keyup)=onEnterClickEvent($event)
           (onBlur)="onOutsideClick($event)"
           placeholder="Eg. Java, Angular, Terraform" 
           class="w-full p-fluid" ></p-autoComplete>
```

Now, there's a scenario I am trying to cater for. Let's say I am a user manually inputting text in this input but for some reason, my text does not give out any search suggestions. Ultimately, I want to be able to include it in the input when I focus out of the  tag. There is an `onBlur` event that can help with that so this is how I handle it:

```
  onOutsideClick(event: KeyboardEvent){
    let tokenInput = event.target as any
    if (tokenInput.value){
      this.skills.push(tokenInput.value)
      tokenInput.value = ""
    }
  }
```

This works to an extent but noticed an issue along the line. When selecting from the search suggestions, it emits an `OnBlur` event before the `onSelect` event. This in turn, runs this code above and includes both the manual input the user was typing, and the selection from the search suggestions, into the input list. Is there a way I could be able to run `onSelect` first and totally ignoring `onBlur` when `onSelect` runs? Any other workaround is appreciated.

I have already tried `setTimeout()` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125841/primeng-autocomplete-onblur-fires-before-onselect-how-to-get-non-matching-value)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired behavior of listening to the blur event of the input field in the autocomplete component and applying a delay before executing logic, you can follow these steps:

1. Add a template reference to the autocomplete component in your HTML file:

```
<h5>Basic</h5>
<p-autoComplete
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
  [suggestions]="filteredCountries"
  (onSelect)="select($event)"
  (completeMethod)="filterCountry($event)"
  #autoRef   <!-- Template reference -->
  field="name"
  [minLength]="1"
></p-autoComplete>
```

2. Import `AfterViewInit` in your component and read the autocomplete component using `@viewChild`:

```
import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AutoComplete } from 'primeng/autocomplete';

export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('autoRef') autoRef: AutoComplete;
  
  // Rest of your component code
}
```

3. Implement the `AfterViewInit` interface in your component:

```js
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.catchBlurEvent();
  }

  // Rest of your component code
}
```

4. Create the `catchBlurEvent()` function in your component. This function listens to the blur event of the input field in the autocomplete component, adds a delay using RxJS `delay()`, and subscribes to the event:

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.catchBlurEvent();
  }

  catchBlurEvent() {
    fromEvent(this.autoRef.inputEL.nativeElement, 'blur')
      .pipe(delay(100))
      .subscribe((event: FocusEvent) => {
        // Your logic here
      });
  }

  // Rest of your component code
}
```

In the `catchBlurEvent()` function, `fromEvent` is used to create an observable from the blur event of the input field in the autocomplete component. The `delay` operator is then applied to introduce a delay of 100 milliseconds. Finally, the subscription handles the event and executes your desired logic.

By implementing these steps, you can listen to the blur event of the autocomplete input field and apply a delay before executing the logic, without the need to use `(onBlur)` in the HTML template.

Comment: Thanks, I had something similar implemented but turns out `nativeElement` is not exposed for some reason:  `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')`

Comment: Actually, tried
`catchBlurEvent() {
    fromEvent(this.autoComplete.el.nativeElement, 'blur')
      .pipe(delay(100))
      .subscribe((event) => {
          console.log(event)
        // Your logic here
      });
  }
`
But, seems it doesnt catch the `blur` event, if I change to `click`, it detects it btw

Comment: You're welcome! If you're trying to catch the `blur` event of the input field, I suggest using `autocomplete.inputEl` instead of `autocomplete.el`. This way, you specifically target the input element rather than the entire autocomplete element.

To avoid the error message "Cannot read properties of undefined," make sure to add the function inside the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. By doing this, you ensure that the necessary elements are initialized before accessing them.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: I'm so sorry if my answer look like generated by an AI ,but honestly 
I take alot of time to answer the question, I know that using AI is illegal and I know that's plagiarism, I always try the solution using `Stackbiltz` and then answer the quesion but sometimes I use paraphrasing Tools  just to restructure the sentences in order to make the answer readable and understandable, I think that is acceptable, isn't it ? @tchrist